# WebServiceCallout soap element missing

Tags: apex, soap

I have a problem calling to an external Webservice from my organization. The callout generated by salesforce does not return any content. Althought, when i call the same webservice from my SOAP client it returns a perfect response.

The apex code has been generate from a WSDL.

This is the request that works in my Soap Client

```
     <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns="http://xxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/1.0">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ns:GetService>
         <ns:ID>123456789</ns:ID>
      </ns:GetService>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is the request that doesn't work, this was generated by Salesforce.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Header />
    <env:Body>
        <GetService xmlns="http://xxxx/xxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx/1.0">
            <ID>123456789</ID>
        </GetService>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

This is my apex code

```
  WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'GetService',
          'http://xxxx/xxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx/1.0',
          'GetService',
          'http://xxxx/xxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx/1.0',
          'Service',
          'Service_element'}
        );
```

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: Are the mismatching and different from `GetService` element names  `GetServiceability` and `GetServicea` typos in your question?

Comment: It was a Typographic error

Comment: The [namespacing](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) looks equivalent to me...

Comment: Ok, I've tested the salesforce request in soap, changing env namespace to http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope and works. Now the point is how do I change that namespace in Salesfoce

Comment: I'll try to talk to the IT team to see if the can change the webservice to accept soap1.1 requests because http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope namespace is only for Soap1.2 actually not supported in salesforce

Comment: Sorry about my earlier comment - was looking at the prefixes and didn't notice the different namespace value...